# How to use "count" in rails to show how many projects/tasks user has?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, model-view-controller, helpermethods

I defined method 'count' in my tasks controller as:

```
def count
  @count = current_user.tasks.count
end
```

I'm not sure how to show that in my tasks views. Do I just use `Tasks count: <% @count %>`? How do I get in my view how many tasks the user has?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, controller methods can't be called directly inside views, instead you need to use helper methods, however Rails still can help you DRY your code and declare a method in controller to to be a helper method that can be used in helpers and views. You can do that by adding this line in the body of Tasks controller:

```
helper_method :count
```

Then inside your view you can just do

```
<%=count%>
```

Btw you can redefine the count method as follows:

```
def count
  current_user.tasks.count
end
```

**However** I don't find a reason why you want to define a method for this in the controller. Were you I would call this directly in the view:

```
<%=current_user.tasks.count%>
```